# Custom CSS grid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve a grid layout with four columns in which one of the columns contains 2 div one on top of another. The image below describes better my target:
[image]

A and B are the CSS classes i've applied on the divs but as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ULHWk/1/ it does not behave as i would desire. The widths and heights of the divs are fixed.

```
<div id="#container">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="B">up</div>
    <div class="B">down</div>
    <div class="A"></div>
</div>

.A {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #00ff00;
}

.B {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #0000ff;
    clear: both;
}
```

Any idea how can I update my css to avchieve the placement as in the image?
Solutions that make use of twitter bootstrap are also acceptable.

**I cannot modify the html in any way, so i'm looking for a solution that would only require CSS.**

Thanks!

Comment: #container....change it to container and follow the solution given below.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ULHWk/5/  please see this fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your just need to make some adjustement with the css :

```
.B {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #0000ff;

}
.B:nth-child(4){
    margin-left: -25%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ULHWk/12/

Hope I help

Comment: Great CSS trick! I was struggling to get that 2nd box floated under correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap B with A and update B width to 100%;

```
<div id="#container">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="A">
        <div class="B">up</div>
        <div class="B">down</div>
    </div>
    <div class="A"></div>
</div>
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ULHWk/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is not possible, i need to do it only by manipulating CSS since the html comes from another source.

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap two div's with class B inside A.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="A">
        <div class="B">up</div>
        <div class="B">down</div>
    </div>
    <div class="A"></div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ULHWk/5/)